# accessing API's from openweathermap

Tags: swift

I am trying to access two bits of data from OpenWeatherMap in Swift.  The first is the description and the second is the temperature.  I am accessing the description using  the following code

```
if let description = ((jsonResult["weather"]as? NSArray)?[0]as? NSDictionary)?["main"]as? String {

                        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute:) {
                            self.resultLabel.text = description
```

Now the issue I am having is accessing the temperature which is configured like this print("Temperature: (weather["main"]!["temp"]!!)") as opposed to print("Weather description: (weather["weather"]![0]!["description"]!!)")
How do I reconfigure the above code to access the temperature data.  Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: `((jsonResult["main"]as? NSArray)?[0]as? NSDictionary)?["temp"]as? String` Mmm... you don't win anything by stuffing that much on the same line, quite the contrary... :p

Comment: So what would you suggest?

Comment: Clearly, I suggest you stop doing that. :) For example, use `if let` or `guard let` to *safely* unwrap your values, step by step, and add `else` clauses to handle possible errors. Don't put everything in one-liners, the code doesn't go faster and it's hard to maintain and debug. Also, use Swift types (typed array instead of NSArray, etc).

Comment: Any reason why I am not getting the temperature when I can access the description of the weather. I think it has to something to do with `if let temperature = ((jsonResult["main"]as? NSArray)?[0]as? NSDictionary)`

Comment: This is why you should do what I suggested, in order to be able to debug your code. In its current state, it's near impossible to debug, because you can't know where it fails.

Comment: I don't need the [0] . So how do I do that with this line.  Thanks for looking into this for me.

Comment: I am now getting this error ' Cast from 'NSArray?' to unrelated type 'NSDictionary' always fails` for the following code `if let temperature = ((jsonResult["main"]as? NSArray)as? NSDictionary)?["temp"]as? String `

Answer (score 0):

After much research this worked for me.

```
if let main = jsonResult["main"] as? NSDictionary {
                        print(main)
                        if let temp = main["temp"] as? Double {
                            DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute:) {
                            self.tempLabel.text = String(format: "%.1fº Centigrade", temp)
                            }
```